# How to change the fully connected network in a GPT model on Huggingface?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, nlp, huggingface-transformers, gpt-2

I'm following [this tutorial on training a causal language model from scratch](https://huggingface.co/learn/nlp-course/chapter7/6).

In the tutorial they load the standard GPT2 as follows:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, GPT2LMHeadModel, AutoConfig

config = AutoConfig.from_pretrained(
    "gpt2",
    vocab_size=len(tokenizer),
    n_ctx=context_length,
    bos_token_id=tokenizer.bos_token_id,
    eos_token_id=tokenizer.eos_token_id,
)
model = GPT2LMHeadModel(config)
```

How can I load the same model, but use my custom fully connected network instead of the standard one? Mainly want to experiment with variations such as more/less layers, different activation functions, etc.

I found the [source code here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/main/src/transformers/models/gpt2/modeling_gpt2.py), but it's very convoluted and I can't figure out how to replace the fully connected parts with a custom ones or what structure the custom one should have in the first place (e.g., input/output size).

**Update**
For example, using a FC network as such:

```
class FC_model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(FC_model, self).__init__()

        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(768,256)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(256,256)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(256,50000)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.sin(self.fc1(x)) + torch.rand(1)
        x = torch.sin(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming by the fully connected network you're referring to the Fully Connected (FC) / [Linear](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Linear.html) layer.

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, GPT2LMHeadModel, AutoConfig, GPT2Config
configuration = GPT2Config()
model = GPT2LMHeadModel(configuration)
print(model)
```

The above would show you the modules inside the model:

```
GPT2LMHeadModel(
  (transformer): GPT2Model(
    (wte): Embedding(50257, 768)
    (wpe): Embedding(1024, 768)
    (drop): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
    (h): ModuleList(
      (0-11): 12 x GPT2Block(
        (ln_1): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
        (attn): GPT2Attention(
          (c_attn): Conv1D()
          (c_proj): Conv1D()
          (attn_dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          (resid_dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
        )
        (ln_2): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
        (mlp): GPT2MLP(
          (c_fc): Conv1D()
          (c_proj): Conv1D()
          (act): NewGELUActivation()
          (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
        )
      )
    )
    (ln_f): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
  )
  (lm_head): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=50257, bias=False)
)
```

You can now access and update the FC layer by:

```
model.lm_head = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Linear(in_features = 768, out_features = 256),
    nn.ReLU(inplace = True),
    nn.Dropout1d(0.25),
    nn.Linear(in_features = 256, out_features = 128)
)
```

The above is just a sample, you can experiment with different combinations.

Comment: This is great and exactly what I meant! Yes, by fully connected I meant the linear layer. I'll accept this answer by EOD, but I was wondering, I never used `nn.Sequential`, is it possible to also use a more flexible implementation? (e.g., see the network in my update)

Comment: Yes it's possible but not in the same way as your new update. Because now you are not just trying to change the FC layer of the model but also modifying the `forward` function of the model which controls the dataflow. In that case, it's better to create your own model class, import the `transformer`/`GPT2Model` module into the `__init__` function and subsequently define the FC layers as you did here. Then update the `forward` function. Please feel free to create a new question as your new update is quite different than the original question.

Answer (score -1):

To experiment with different hyperparameters, you can use the **Autoclass** provided by HG. This class allows you to create a custom architecture with a base class from one of the available models on the HG hub. For instance, if you want to experiment with the number of layers, you can pass a config parameter and change the layer number to the desired value. Like `"n_layers": 6.` To learn more, please refer to the following link: https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/create_a_model.